# How to change icons onPress in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im new to React Native so excuse the question if this is simple. 
Im trying to toggle icons in a ListView. I'm logging out the correct response but Im unable to see the screen refresh onPress with that icon using "this.state". How should I go about this? Your help is much appreciated.

Here's a piece of code i'm working with.

```js
getInitialState: function() {
   return {liked:false};
}, 

pressedLike: function(){ 
    this.setState({liked: !this.state.liked})
},

renderRow: function (data) {
    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableHighlight
              onPress={()=>{this.pressedLike}}>
                <View>
                    {this.state.liked ? <Icon name="ios-heart" size={25} color="red" />   : <Icon name="ios-heart-outline" size={25} color="#555" />}
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
       </View>
  );
},

render: function() {
    return (
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow}
            refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl refreshing={this.state.refreshing} onRefresh=   {this.onRefresh}/>
    }
/>

  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple, here is an example of how to change an Awesome icon on press... using the node_module react-native-vector-icon available on GitHub.

First in `getInitialState`, declare a variable with the icon you want and a check var to know which logo to display:

```
return {logo: "star-o", check: false}
```

Then on the concerned button / clickable zone , add this method:

```
onPress={() => this.stateChange()}
```

And declare a `stateChange` method and add this:

```
this.state.check === false ? this.setState({logo:'star', check:true}) : this.setState({logo:'star-o', check:false})
```

This looks for the check var and changes the logo depending on its value. It is ternary syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There's really a lot that needs to happen here. You're going to probably need some sort of data structure that has a liked boolean in it, something like this (just an example):

```
data = [{name: 'Dog', liked: false}, {name: 'Turtle', liked: false}, {name: 'Cat', liked: false}]
```

Then in your `likeItem` method, you will need to get the index of the item you are looping over and update the liked boolean, and reset the state of the dataSource:

```
likeItem (index) {
  const { data } = this.state
  data[index].liked = !data[index].liked
  this.setState({ dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data), data })
}
```

And you can show the icon based on the liked value:

```
{rowData.liked && <LikedIcon />}
{!rowData.liked && <NotLikedIcon />}
```

I wipped up a quick example of the functionality you may need [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/H2hsSg).

https://rnplay.org/apps/H2hsSg